# how to find selected fields from sample data in nested array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have sample collection of data

```
[
  {
    data: [
      {
        "id": "0001",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Cake",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters": {
          "batter": [
            {
              "id": "1001",
              "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
              "id": "1002",
              "type": "Chocolate"
            },
            {
              "id": "1003",
              "type": "Blueberry"
            },
            {
              "id": "1004",
              "type": "Devil's Food"
            }
          ]
        },
        "topping": [
          {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "None"
          },
          {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "Glazed"
          },
          {
            "id": "5005",
            "type": "Sugar"
          },
          {
            "id": "5007",
            "type": "Powdered Sugar"
          },
          {
            "id": "5006",
            "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles"
          },
          {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "Chocolate"
          },
          {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "Maple"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0002",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Raised",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters": {
          "batter": [
            {
              "id": "1001",
              "type": "Regular"
            }
          ]
        },
        "topping": [
          {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "None"
          },
          {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "Glazed"
          },
          {
            "id": "5005",
            "type": "Sugar"
          },
          {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "Chocolate"
          },
          {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "Maple"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "0003",
        "type": "donut",
        "name": "Old Fashioned",
        "ppu": 0.55,
        "batters": {
          "batter": [
            {
              "id": "1001",
              "type": "Regular"
            },
            {
              "id": "1002",
              "type": "Chocolate"
            }
          ]
        },
        "topping": [
          {
            "id": "5001",
            "type": "None"
          },
          {
            "id": "5002",
            "type": "Glazed"
          },
          {
            "id": "5003",
            "type": "Chocolate"
          },
          {
            "id": "5004",
            "type": "Maple"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and I need data only in this formate of a specific id.

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55
  }
]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$data"
},
{
  "$match": {
    "data.id": "0001"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": "$data.id",
    "type": "$data.type",
    "name": "$data.name",
    "ppu": "$data.ppu"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpMVFSL66oW)